# Python C-API equivalent of "python -m module_name" (python 2.7)

Tags: cpython, python-c-api

Having looked the Python C-API documentation, I cannot figure out a way to execute a python script given just the name of the module (from c or c++ code).

Is there an equivalent C-API function for `python -m module_name`?

I am using Python 2.7 embedded in a C++ executable.

Answer (score 1):

This is done with the standard library runpy module ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html); [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/runpy.py)). You just need to call the (undocumented) function `runpy._run_module_as_main(module_name)`.

The [C API code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/06e7608207daab9fb82d13ccf2d3664535442f11/Modules/main.c#L192) used by the Python interpreter just imports that module, gets the `_run_module_as_main` attribute and calls it (i.e. uses `runpy` as a Python module).